# Como permitir execução de javascript em linha? (extensão google)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extensão

Olá, eu estava montando uma extensão que recebia urls em um formulário e adicionava novos campos quando um botão fosse pressionado. Executando como html normal o código funciona, mas quando eu executo como extensão ele retorna esse erro:

```
Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the 
following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: 
filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' 
keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required 
to enable inline execution.
```

HTML usado:

```
<form id="formulario">
  <input type="url" class="campo" placeholder="endereço..." />
  <div onclick="sis_interface.novocampo();" class="novocampo"></div>
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT usado:

```
var sis_interface = {
  novocampo : function() {
    document.getElementById("formulario").innerHTML += '<input type="url" class="campo" placeholder="endereço..." />';
  }
}
```

Agradeço desde já a ajuda.

Comment: Tente olhar esse tópico: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36622181/how-to-fix-chrome-extension-inline-javascript-invocation-error

Comment: Os scripts estão no mesmo domínio da página?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Resposta obtida do link [How to fix chrome-extension inline JavaScript invocation error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36622181/how-to-fix-chrome-extension-inline-javascript-invocation-error) (resposta no SO em inglês).

Comment: Seria mais interessante você resumir a resposta aqui, pois por mais que seja do Soen, queremos que nossos posts aqui sejam independentes na medida do possivel, e sua resposta, caso algum dia o autor ou a resposta seja apagada, perde totalmente o sentido.

Comment: faz sentido, de fato.